# TeamSpeak3 libraries

Tags: freebsd, libraries, teamspeak

I've downloaded the `TeamSpeak 3` server from their official website (it's 64 bit, as my dedicated server is 64 bit too).

This is what I get,when I'm trying to run the server:

```
Starting the TeamSpeak 3 server
TeamSpeak 3 server started, for details please view the log file
/libexec/ld-elf.so.1: scott# /lib/libiconv.so.3: unsupported file layout
```

Whats wrong? /libexec/ld-elf.so.1 exists, same as the second one, is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

What distro are you running? Need more information.

If your TS3 server is 64-bit and you're on a Fedora or Red Hat derived distribution, you're getting that error because all the binaries in /lib are *32-bit* and you can't load 32-bit images into a 64-bit address space.

You might need to add /lib64 to your /etc/ld.so.conf file (and then run ldconfig) or export the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib64, like this:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib64
```

Comment: I'm using FreeBSD @tags Are the steps you specified are similar on FreeBSD?

Comment: Bah, silly tags. State it in your question! :) But yeah, FreeBSD follows the Red Hat philosophy of /lib and /usr/lib being 32-bit and /usr/lib64 and /lib64 being 64-bit. It's trying to load a 32-bit image into a 64-bit address space. That would also explain why I didn't recognize the error message "unsupported file layout" from Linux's errno implementation...

Comment: Also are you running the Linux version of Teamspeak3 or are you running a native FreeBSD version?

Comment: Native FreeBSD version.

Comment: There is no `ld.so.conf` file in the `/etc` path.

Comment: Don't worry overly much about ld.so.conf. Modifying the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable has the same effect, so try that first. If it works then you know that it's a dynamic linker path problem and can then figure out separately how to make this "permanent", either by writing a wrapper script or by modifying FreeBSD's own variation on the ld.so.conf theme.

Comment: I also leave you with a fantastic link to the world-famous TLDP. Read specifically the notes on "other UNIXes" in these sections. http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html

Comment: @allquixotic, FreeBSD does not have a lib64. It has a lib32 directory. Teamspeak is a Linux binary, and the linux emulation is always 32bit. So if it is a linux binary you need the 32bit version

Comment: On the other hand there is no /lib/libiconv.so.3 in FreeBSD. Where does this file come from?

Comment: @arved, Scott said that he's running the native FreeBSD version, not the Linux version. Are you sure it's a Linux binary?

Comment: well output of file and ldd would definetly help to shed some light into this issue

Comment: Problem solved. I had to remove the `/lib/libiconv.so.3` library and then the problem was gone. Kinda strange.

Answer (score 0):

FreeBSD does not have a lib64. It has a lib32 directory.

Teamspeak is a Linux binary, and the linux emulation is always 32bit. So if it is a linux binary you need the 32bit version

On the other hand there is no `/lib/libiconv.so.3` in FreeBSD. Delete that file & it should work fine

Comment: You have plenty of rep to comment